# Need Help in kamailio push notification for IOS

Tags: kamailio

I need to configure ios push notification in kamailio I have installed kamailio by repository. and need to configure ios push notification for my custom app. kindly support.

Comment: Kamailio is a SIP Proxy, typically used for VoIP. It does not handle iOS push notifications.

Comment: I have a php script for sending push notification and kamailio have a module called http_client for calling php via http protocol now i want to handle push notification, i read here https://medium.com/@denys.pozniak/apple-push-notification-with-kamailio-eeca2f8e08d but not able to understand because it is not clear

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this

1) Create fast and simple http endpoint running on localhost which will get device name from kamailio(sent via http module) and write it to  rabbitmq.

2) Create php script which read device name, searches for credentials and does push(reuse of your current php script).

It is higly recommend use somethign like above, becuase kamailio http module block event loop.

Comment: Hello Arheops, I not understand what your want to say kindly explain with some examples

Comment: Likly you just need hire someone with more background in kamailio and scripting

Comment: The http_async_client module for Kamailio does not block when making HTTP requests. 

Comment: Yes, but it is available from v4.4 only.